# Modifying a function pointer passed to a method?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

Is there any way to pass a function pointer to an Objective C method, and then have that method modify the function pointer to point at a C function somewhere else?

Creating a method that accepts a function pointer is simple enough:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithFunctionPointer:(void(*)(/* args go here */))functionPointer;
```

I can then call that function inside doSomethingWithFunctionPointer simply by calling:

```
if (functionPointer)
{
    functionPointer();
}
```

But what if I actually wanted to change the functionPointer to point at something else within doSomethingWithFunctionPointer, so that any code outside that method can then call the changed function pointer to call the function that doSomethingWithFunctionPointer point it to?

I know this is probably a prime example of how not to do things in Objective C (especially considering we've got blocks and what not). It's more just curiosity at this point. It almost sounds like I'd need a function pointer pointer, but I'm not sure how that would work, if it's even possible.

Comment: If I understood your case, you're talking about a variable of type pointer to function. You can always change the value pointed by a pointer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using pointers to function pointers. Perhaps the most readable way to do it is to `typedef` your function pointer, like this:

```
typedef void (*FunPtr)(int a, float b);
```

Then use a pointer of that `typedef`-ed type to assign in a function, like this:

```
void foo(int a, float b) {
    printf("FOO : %d %f\n", a, b);
}

void bar(int a, float b) {
    printf("BAR : %d %f\n", a, b);
}

// This function receives a pointer to function pointer
void assign(int n, FunPtr *ptr) {
    if (n == 0) {
        *ptr = foo;
    } else {
        *ptr = bar;
    }
}
```

Here is how you call `assign` from your code:

```
int main(void) {
    FunPtr f;
    assign(0, &f);
    f(10, 20.5);
    assign(1, &f);
    f(10, 20.5);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Vgpb7g)

**Note:** You are right about blocks in Objective-C greatly reducing the need for direct use of function pointers. However, you can use a similar `typedef` trick with pointers to blocks.